# list ACL for storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-rbac

i want to list access that were provided on storage via ACL.

Is there a API solution for this?

I want to list all entities (AD group, Service Principal etc) (like one marked in green) that has access to storage via  ACLs

Idea is to create audit platform which can list all access that are provided via ACL

[image]

I tried path, as suggested in one of the comment. "x-ms-acl" is missing in response. (refer screenshot)
[image]

after changing blob to "dfs" in blob, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you would want to use is [`Path - Get Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/get-properties) with `action` query parameter as `getAccessControl`. This should return you ACL in `x-ms-acl` response header.

You will need to use DFS endpoint (instead of blob endpoint).

[image]

If you are using [`Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/) (.Net SDK for Azure DataLake), the method you would want to use is [`DataLakeDirectoryClient.GetAccessControlAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakedirectoryclient.getaccesscontrolasync?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: modified original post.

Comment: I believe you will need to use `dfs` endpoint instead of `blob` endpoint. Can you try with `https://account.dfs.core.windows.net`?

Comment: worked. now some thought experiment. how to create an audit system? going recursive inside each storage doesnt sound feasible and doing it on periodic basis might kill the process and storage itself. But i remember when i assign ACL, it says give execute to same user at all parent levels. so can i assume that all ACLs (atleast execute) has to start at container level itself? if that is true, i might just run above code at all container level. this is lengthy too, but still feasible. your thoughts?